# How can I split every characters in a string except "&nbsp;"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

## My problem (fixed)

---

I'm trying to make an animation where every letters appears one after the other, but the problem is that I have to set a div around my `span` tags to "`flex`", otherwise they can't be transformed (`inline-block` doesn't allow you to do this). The space present between two words is now as if "non-existent", and the words are wrapped together without space.

I'm using NuxtJS to do this. Here's what I have so far:

```html
<div :class="$style['intro-chars']">
  <span
   v-for="(char, i) of text.split('')"
   :key="i"
   ref="title"
   :class="{ space: i == 6 }"
  >
  {{ char }} <!-- "text" is defined in a data() method -->
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
.intro-chars {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    span {
      font-size: 6em;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
  }

.space {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```js
let title = this.$refs.title;
console.log(title);

for (let i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
  gsap.timeline({ defaults: { duration: 1.8, ease: "power4.inOut", delay: 0.1 * i } }).fromTo(title[i], { translateY: 100 }, { translateY: 0 });
}
```

## Solution

---

I finally managed to make it happen by passing my data in a computed method.

I replaced the whitespace of my string by a `_`.

I then operated on that data by indexing `_` and replacing it with `\u00A0` by doing this:

```js
computed: {
 splitText() {
   let split = this.text.split('');
   split[split.indexOf("_")] = "\u00A0"
   return split;
}
```

In my `v-for`, it ain't `(char, i) of text` anymore but `(char, i) of splitText` (as in the computed method).

It then returns me `&nbsp;` in a single `span`, instead of a split `&nbsp;` into multiple separated `span` such as `<span>&</span> <span>n</span> <span>b</span>…`.

Comment: You should separate question and answer so that they may be voted on separately.  In this case the question is useful, but your answer is not a good solution. So the only option is to down vote the question.  -1

Comment: Hi, please post your own answer here.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you want to split string in chars without spaces.

If that so try this code

```js
title.replace(/ +/g, '').split('');
```